# css module not apply to react component after Webpack build

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, webpack, tsx

I'm currently working with the latest version of Webpack to build files from TSX and SCSS files, so my issue is after building files to JS and CSS modules. all of the styles don't apply to any react components,

you can see my configure below

This is my SCSS file.

```
// Home.module.scss
.addgame {
  background-color: aqua;
}
```

My React file

```
import React from 'react';

const styles = require('./Home.module.scss');

export default function HomePage() {
  return (
    <div className={styles.addgame}>HomePage</div>
  );
}
```

I have 2 files of Webpack

```
//Webpack.config.js
// const webpack = require('webpack');
const { merge } = require('webpack-merge');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');

const common = require('./webpack.common.js');

module.exports = merge(common, {
  mode: 'production',
  devtool: 'source-map',
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      hash: true,
      template: './src/index.html',
      minify: {
        removeComments: true,
        collapseWhitespace: true,
        removeRedundantAttributes: true,
        useShortDoctype: true,
        removeEmptyAttributes: true,
        removeStyleLinkTypeAttributes: true,
        keepClosingSlash: true,
        minifyJS: true,
        minifyCSS: true,
        minifyURLs: true,
      },
    }),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: '[name].[contenthash].css',
      chunkFilename: '[id].[contenthash].css',
    }),
  ],
  optimization: {
    moduleIds: 'deterministic',
    runtimeChunk: true,
  }
});
```

this is common Webpack

```
//webpack.common.js
const path = require('path');
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const { WebpackManifestPlugin } = require('webpack-manifest-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');

module.exports = {
  context: process.cwd(),
  entry: {
    index: './src/index.tsx',
  },
  plugins: [new CleanWebpackPlugin({ cleanStaleWebpackAssets: false }), new WebpackManifestPlugin()],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.ts(x?)$/,
        use: ['babel-loader', 'ts-loader'],
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
        use: [
          {
            loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
            options: {
              modules: {
                namedExport: true,
              },
            },
          },
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
              modules: true,
              // Run `postcss-loader` on each CSS `@import`, do not forget that `sass-loader` compile non CSS `@import`'s into a single file
              // If you need run `sass-loader` and `postcss-loader` on each CSS `@import` please set it to `2`
              importLoaders: 2,
            },
          },
          'postcss-loader',
          'sass-loader',
        ],
      },
      {
        // asset
        test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|jpeg|gif)$/i,
        type: 'asset/resource',
      },
      {
        // asset
        test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|otf)$/i,
        type: 'asset/resource',
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js', 'scss'],
  },
  output: {
    filename: '[name].[contenthash].js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../build'),
    pathinfo: false,
    publicPath: '/',
  },
};
```

```
//postcss configure
module.exports = {
    plugins: [
        "postcss-preset-env",
        "postcss-modules"
    ]
}
```

```
///babel
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "useBuiltIns": "usage",
        "corejs": 3
      }
    ],
    ["@babel/preset-typescript"],
    ["@babel/preset-flow"],
    ["@babel/preset-react"]
  ],
  "plugins": [
    ["@babel/plugin-transform-flow-strip-types"],
    ["const-enum"],
    ["@babel/plugin-transform-typescript"],
    ["@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import"],
    ["@loadable/babel-plugin"]
  ]
}
```

Comment: The name of the css files is AddGame.module.scss or Home.module.scss? because addgame class is in AddGame.module.scss, but you are importing Home.module.scss

Comment: @lissettdm it's `Home.module.scss`, I pasted the wrong one

Comment: Do you have a reproducible repo?

Comment: @lissettdm I don't have it, I'll make one